# Scrolling on small windows screen

Tags: resolution, scrolling

EeePc has a tiny screen, and it scrolls to show the toolbar and task bar of windows. It never used to do this, I tried lowering the resolution, but it's at the lowest possible. Any thoughts how to stop the scrolling for the task bar?

Answer (score 3):

When you lower the resolution, it increases the size of the taskbar, causing you to have to scroll it if you wish to see all open windows. What you want to do is set it to the highest resolution possible in order to eliminate scrolling.